# Fragment no longer exists for key android:target_state

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I think I have same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935224/fragement-no-longer-exists-for-key-f0-index-1) but there is no answer.

I have an Activity with an ViewPager and a FrameLayout which will contain a Fragment. It look like this :

```
Activity
   |— ViewPager 
          |-FragmentA
   |— Framelayout 
        |— FragmentB
              |— FragmentC (here I called fragmentC.setTargetFragment method).
```

When I rotate the device. I 'll get this error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10354): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment no longer exists for key android:target_state: index 1
E/AndroidRuntime(10354):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:586)
E/AndroidRuntime(10354):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
E/AndroidRuntime(10354):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
E/AndroidRuntime(10354):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1118)
E/AndroidRuntime(10354):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1922)
E/AndroidRuntime(10354):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1776)
E/AndroidRuntime(10354):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
E/AndroidRuntime(10354):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
E/AndroidRuntime(10354):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1118)
E/AndroidRuntime(10354):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1922)
E/AndroidRuntime(10354):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:266)
E/AndroidRuntime(10354):    at com.example.android.animationsdemo.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:20)
```

Everything work fine if I don't call fragmentC.setTargetFragment method or I don't set the Adapter for the Viewpager. 
Here are my Code :

Activity :

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        TabsAdapter tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyFragmentB fragmentA = new MyFragmentB();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.flContainer, fragmentA,
                        "TAG").addToBackStack("back").commit();
            }
        });


    }

    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final Context mContext;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;

            TabInfo tabInfo = new TabInfo(MyFragmentA.class, null);
            mTabs.add(tabInfo);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }
    }

}
```

The Activity layout :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Fragment B"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dip"
        android:id="@+id/flContainer" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="wrtadfa"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And FragmentA :

```
public class MyFragmentA extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        return myFragmentView;
    }
}
```

FragmentA layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="It's Fragment A" />

</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentB :

```
public class MyFragmentB extends Fragment implements MyFragmentC.CallBack {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);

        myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyFragmentC fragmentA = new MyFragmentC();

                //This caused the problem
                fragmentA.setTargetFragment(MyFragmentB.this, 0);

                getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.flContainer2, fragmentA, "TAG").addToBackStack("back").commit();
            }
        });

        return myFragmentView;
    }
}
```

fragment_b.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#888888"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="It's Fragment B" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/c_received"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Fragment C"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContainer2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentC :

```
public class MyFragmentC extends Fragment {

    public static interface CallBack{
        //some call back
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        if(getTargetFragment() != null){
            CallBack callBack = (CallBack) getTargetFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, container, false);

        return myFragmentView;
    }
}
```

fragment_c.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#888888"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="It's Fragment C" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I know that I can work around by let the Activity implement the MyFragmentC.CallBack instead of FragmentB implement it.
But I just curious why does it happen ???
If I don't set Adapter for the viewpager or don't call "setTargetFragment" in FragmentC. Then everything work fine.

So sorry because I don't know how to format the code well in here and it's a long post. Any help could be appreciate.

Answer (score 12):

Please have a look into google's discussion thread where they are suggested to remove setTargetFragment() and instead use getParentFragment(). More detail is provided here : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54520

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about your getItem() method in your adapter. Rather then using FragmentPagerAdapter you can use FragmentStatePagerAdapter and put an if check for your getItem method. After pausing and resuming (in your case this is orientation change) probably your reference to the object get lost.

In google dev forums they also say not to use setTargetFragment method since it is buggy, you can try using getParentFragment for that reason.